# How to call a specific function from a Class from via command line in python

Tags: python, command-line

I have a python file test1.py which has following code (for example) -

```
class Testing(BaseTestRemote):

    def collect_logs(self):

    def delete_logs(self):
```

So how do I run only collect_logs() (present in class Testing) from command line, can you please give an example?

Comment: You just call it. `Testing().collect_logs()` Command line and non-interactive python are (nearly) identically. Is there some catch in your case?

Comment: You will need to write a command line interface and tell that what each argument means. For example, see `argparse`.

Answer (score 1):

Let's make a file named `file.py` with the following contents:

```
class test(object):

    def __init__(self):
        return

    def square(self, x):
        return x*x

    def cube(self, x):
        return x*x*x
```

Run the command line from the directory that contains `file.py` and do the following:

```
~$ python
Python 2.7.11+ (default, Apr 17 2016, 14:00:29) 
[GCC 5.3.1 20160413] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import file
>>> obj = file.test()
>>> obj.square(2)
4
>>> obj.cube(4)
64
>>> from file import test
>>> test().square(2)
4
>>> test().square(4)
16
>>> x = test()
>>> x.square(2)
4
>>> x.square(4)
16
>>>
```